# Creating shootgun shoot by instantiate function (Unity C#)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have problem with instantiate function, if I shoot in different rotation, shape of this shoot changed. In x axis (streaight from respawn)  it looks good (cone), but for example in y axis it looks "flat". Any  ideas how to fix it?
Code here:

```
pellets[i] = Random.rotation;
p = (GameObject)Instantiate(pellet, barrelExit.position, barrelExit.rotation);
Destroy(p, lifeTime);
p.transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(p.transform.rotation, pellets[i], spreadAngle);
p.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(p.transform.right * pelletFireVelocity);
```

Comment: Did you find an answer to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand your use of `RotatateTowards` by fixed angle instead of randomizing it feels like it would generate more or less empty cone, however might not understand that. I think you should replace `spreadAngle` with `Random.Range(0.f, spreadAngle)`

Also on the side note I think you should give a try to object pooling.

Answer (score 0):

`Random.rotation` is inappropriate here. You're not interested in sampling from every possible rotation, only rotations around your camera's forward.

Instead, use [`Random.Range`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Random.Range.html) to get a value between`-spreadAngle` and `spreadAngle`. Then, you can rotate that much around your camera's forward using [`Quaternion.AngleAxis`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.AngleAxis.html) and multiplying the result by the barrel's rotation.

This is also preferable to using `RotateTowards` to clamp your spray, as that would result in more pellets being fired around the edges of the spray. Using `Random.Range` and `Quaternion.AngleAxis` will result in a uniform distribution.:

```
Camera mainCam; // cache result of Camera.main here for performance

Start()
{
...
    mainCam = Camera.main;
...
}

...

float randomAngle = Random.Range(-spreadAngle, spreadAngle);
pellets[i] = Quaternion.AngleAxis(randomAngle, mainCam.forward) * barrelExit.rotation;
p = (GameObject)Instantiate(pellet, barrelExit.position, barrelExit.rotation);
Destroy(p, lifeTime);
p.transform.rotation = pellets[i]; 
p.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(p.transform.right * pelletFireVelocity);
```

By the way, you should consider [pooling](https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/object-pooling) these pellets, rather than creating and destroying many of them at a time.